# WINAPI: How do I convert short names to long names on a REMOTE computer?

Tags: c++, winapi, registry, remote-access

Normally it is easy to change the registry on a remote machine by using a handle created by RegConnectRegistry(), which can be passed into functions like RegOpenKeyEx() and RegSetValueEx(), etc.

However, the functions GetLongPathName() and GetShortPathName() don't take in a handle and so can (I assume) only be used on the machine from which it is being called.

I have a short name (C:\PROGRA~1\APP~1\APP~1.DLL) on a remote machine (with IP address 10.0.103.108) that I want to convert to long name using GetLongPathName():

```
DWORD WINAPI GetLongPathName(
  _In_  LPCTSTR lpszShortPath,
  _Out_ LPTSTR  lpszLongPath,
  _In_  DWORD   cchBuffer
);
```

As the short name `_In_  LPCTSTR lpszShortPath` parameter, I've tried using:

C:\PROGRA~1\APP~1\APP~1.DLL
\\10.0.103.108\C:\PROGRA~1\APP~1\APP~1.DLL 
\\10.0.103.108\C$\PROGRA~1\APP~1\APP~1.DLL

None of them work when passed as the _in_ parameter to [GetLongPathName()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364980(v=vs.85).aspx). For each case, I've been getting the respective error codes:

3 (ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND)
67 (ERROR_BAD_NET_NAME)
2 (ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)

Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: Aren't short names supposed to be used for DOS compatibility?

Comment: Why do you have a shortname in the first place?

Comment: It's stored in the REG_SZ value `AppInit_DLLs` under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows`.  
  
Basically I have to index each DLL (delimited by commas or spaces), convert them to long name, check if their path contains a certain substring, and then remove them if that's the case.

Comment: What does the Registry API using handles have to do with it?

Comment: @EJP it's not relevant.

Comment: You might try opening the remote file and then calling `GetFinalPathNameByHandle` see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364962(v=vs.85).aspx